# Not able to pass the hidden test in year to century program c

Tags: c

My code on codefights works well for all the test cases but doesn't pass one hidden test case. The problem is to convert the given year from 1<=year<=2005 into century.

I wrote all the code. I just don't get what I should change to get the hidden test passed.

This is my code:

```
int centuryFromYear(int year)
{
    while(year>=1&&year<=2005)
    {
        int x=year/100;
        if(year%10==0)
        {
            return(x);
        }
        else 
        {
            return(x+1);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: What test case specifically is your code failing? What is the expected and actual output for that case?

Comment: @RobertColumbia The problem is the OP doesn't know. Probably "close as unclear what you're asking"?

Comment: This is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @user202729 interpreting from the OP's introduction, there can only be 2005 possible test cases. Figuring out the correct result for all of them shouldn't be *too* hard.

Comment: Note that you don't need a while loop here.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Of course it's easy if they already have the corresponding 2005 answers.

Comment: that is the problem i dont know where it is failing. It just shows that it is a hidden test case where it fails. dont know what case.@RobertColumbia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected Code -

```
int centuryFromYear(int year)
{
    int x=year/100;

    if(year%100==0)
    {
        return(x);
    }
    else 
    {
        return(x+1);
    }

}
```

You were almost there too.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The part you're off on is when a century starts/ends.

The 20th century is from 1901 - 2000, the 19th century from 1801 - 1900, etc.  So the result is to divide the year by 100 (right so far), then add 1 to the result unless the year is divisible by *100*, not 10 as you have.

So instead of:

```
if(year%10==0)
```

You want:

```
if(year%100==0)
```

Also, the `while` loop is not needed.  You can remove it entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming year is positive,

```
int centuryFromYear (int year)
{
    return (year + 99) / 100;
}
```

would suffice